# Where can I buy industry quality ready prototype construction set?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, prototyping

I am designing a mechanical machine. I have constructed it successfully using children's construction set like [Merkur](https://www.merkurtoys.cz/). The machine I made makes a lot of rotation. Consequently, the children's construction set cannot endure the stress (the parts bent, the screws and nuts fly apart) in order for me to carry out the tests successfully. I need much stronger and preferably also bigger parts in order to test my mechanical machine. I could of course design everything in CAD and ask some manufacturer to make the whole machine for me or the individual parts. However, this is quite time consuming and expensive, especially given I may need to iterate on the design.

Is there out there some prototype construction set made from strong materials (e.g. hardened steel, titanium, hardened carbon) that contains a great variety of parts (e.g. wheels, cog wheels; rods, and bars; chains, and belts; connecting parts - L-shape, U-shape, flat - square, long narrow rectangle, triangle) that is compatible with other freely available standard parts (e.g. screws, nuts)?

The idea is that I would just use a construction set like that to iterate through my mechanical prototype before stabilizing the CAD design.

Comment: Not from hardened materials, no. Servocity sells compatible pieces that all work together to be an aluminum erector set with the bells and whistles you ask for which is considerably more durable than toys like Merkur. They are sold by the piece though so you can build a kit but you will need to fork out the cash. You might actually save money by getting a drill press, a set of drills, transfer punches, mallet, scribe, and combination square to make the beams yourself and only buy the Lynxmotion parts that are not beams. And a bandsaw or hacksaw. Also a file & manual countersink for deburring,

Comment: And you don't need hardened steel at all for most purposes, let alone titanium or carbon which you will all pay through the nose for. Mild steel is actually really tough. Have you ever taken a hand drill or hacksaw to mild steel? Going from wood to aluminum is only a little bit more difficult but going from aluminum to mild steel is a big surprise.

Comment: Search "robotics sheet metal kit" for some metal "children's construction set" that might work.  Some results might be more expensive than the local shop's scrap 20 gauge.  For custom gears and cogs, consider getting a 3D printer.  A set of metalworking prototyping tools will go a long way to saving money as already mentioned.

Comment: I do not have a proper workshop and need high precision parts. Looking at Servocity products, I think I will go with them unless somebody brings up a better suggestion.

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: @DávidNatingga If you can afford it you may consider actually ordering the parts to be made. You could start with the most important parts and use the toy set for everything that it can handle. Do not be afraid to buy metal rods, L-shapes etc from the hardware store and drill holes in them.

Comment: you might be building it poorly. For example you want to support axles on both sides except for very light loads.

Answer (score 1):

First step if you find that your children's toy prototype is failing should be attempting to figure out the forces you are putting on it and seeing whether they can be distributed better. Sometimes adding a truss or two will greatly improve the strength of the construction.

Aluminum extrusions are the material of choice for rapid prototyping of machines.

Those come with T-slots along the sides in which connectors can fit and be screwed down in various different orientations.

Drilling into aluminum is fairly easy with a metal drill, as is tapping threads for machine screws. That way you can attach bearing blocks for the rotating shafts that you seem to need.

If aluminum extrusions end up too bulky for your mechanism then 3D printed parts can be a solution.